# Magento 2: How can display Name of Tax Rule on product page

Tags: magento2, customer, product-page, group, tax-rule

I create two tax rule name **rule1** and **disability tax** ,check below images [image]

Now I want to display these two tax rule names on the product page. any help will be appreciated. [image]

Comment: do you need to display all the rule name in the product detail page ?

Answer (score 1):

**Create Module with the following code, this will give you exactly that you are looking for :D**

=> **app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

=> **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

=> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\TexRuleNames" name="tex.rule.names" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/text_rule_names.phtml" after="product.info.price" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

=> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/TexRuleNames.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class TexRuleNames extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRuleCollection $taxRuleCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_taxRuleCollection = $taxRuleCollection;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getTextRuleNames()
    {
        return $this->_taxRuleCollection->getColumnValues('code');
    }
}
```

=> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/text_rule_names.phtml**

```
<?php $TextRuleName = $block->getTextRuleNames(); ?>

<div class="text-rules">
    <?php foreach ($TextRuleName as $rule): ?>
        <h1><?php echo $rule; ?></h1>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: where exactly you want this in detail page?

Comment: hi @irshad, i have updated my answer with all required file.

Comment: what errors are you facing ?

Comment: hi @irshad, check line number 12 in Vendor\Module\Block\TexRuleNames here i added $ twice in $taxRuleCollection, correct it in your code

Comment: hi @irshad, working now?