# Magento 2: How can dynamically display Name of Tax Rule on product page

Tags: customer-group, product-page, group, tax-rule

To display Name of **tax rule** on the **product details page** I creat a module through this link ([Magento 2: How can display Name of Tax Rule on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303294/magento-2-how-can-display-name-of-tax-rule-on-product-page/303358?noredirect=1#comment437279_303358)). And it's working successfully check below images [image]  [image]
Now I want it dynamically, which means,I created two tax rules for two stores **US and IN**, I need while customers click on  **US-tax rule** or **IN-tax rule** on the product page, the price automatically calculate accordingly. check below images product price change on the selected stores. 
1> **default store product price is $60.00**  [image]
2> **when select **US store** product price $64.95** [image]
3> **when select **IN store** product price $63.00**  [image]
now I want above changes of price on click of **US-tax rule** and **IN-tax rule**.

Comment: i think tax rule are applied on the basis of country and region, customer cant select tax rule maybe

Comment: @hiren: you are right. I create two tax rule for two different country store  **US and IN** I need while customer chooses tax rule on product page automatically calculate it according to set store. I updated my question please check

Comment: ok you just need it for display purpose right ?

Comment: @hiren: yes for display purpose and also while adding to cart product price calculation should be accordingly.

Comment: checkout this link may it help you : https://gielberkers.com/get-product-price-including-excluding-tax-magento-2/

Comment: @hiren: Product price change in the selected stores. 1> **default store product price is $60.00**
2> when select store **IN, store product price $63.00**
3> when select store **US, store product price $64.95**
I want above changes of price on click of **US-tax rule and IN-tax rule.**
i updated my answer please check I think  i am vey near to what I need

Comment: hi @hiren: I have an idea,  we can change the position of **store switcher**  in the place of Tax-rule name on the product page.?.
for this i have <move element="header.switchers" destination="footer.panel.container" after="-"/>  . what will be destination for product page just above the product price.?